# IE11 Regular Expression Unexpected Result

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, flatpickr

I have this regular expression `/(\d\d|\d).(\d\d|\d)/` and I'm executing it on `06/16/2018` as the input string. In Chrome, it works as expected, giving `["06/16", "06", "16"]` as the match results. In IE11, it's giving me `["2018", "20", "8"]` as the results. However, when I attempt to recreate it in the console directly, it works fine in both browsers. Any idea what could be happening here?

For background, this is actually executed in a third party library [flatpickr](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) v4.5.0 but I'm debugging that code to see what's happening.

See below screenshot from the IE11 debugger for an example. I can't figure out how this could be happening.

[image: Screenshot from IE Debugger]

It doesn't make any sense to me, how could `(\d\d|\d).(\d\d|\d)` match `06/16/2018` as `2018` instead of `06/16`. Also, look at `match`'s `index` property. 11? How is that even possible? The input string's length is only 10.

Here's a link to a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zxkyq5x0mp) where this is demonstrated.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] which shows the actual problem

Comment: this sounds like the same RegExp object is `exec`uted twice on the same string

Comment: @Thomas as far as I can tell, the RegExp is created each time it is `exec`ed, so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out the issue, so I wanted to follow up here for anyone that finds this in the future.

As you can see in the code sandbox link that I posted above, I was getting the formatted date string by using [Date.toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString). Apparently, in IE11 (and Edge), there are some additional Left-To-Right characters included, which was throwing off the parsing of the formatted date value. Once I got rid of these characters, this issue was resolved.

For reference, here's the GitHub issue I opened to track this issue: https://github.com/IBM/carbon-components-react/issues/1325